# Joined tables returning correct value when selecting single row but incorrect when entire dataset

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, many-to-many, left-join

I have 3 tables which I have joined: campaign level, ad level, and keyword level, and I need certain things from each of these. All 3 contain the following identical columns: campaign_name, campaign_id, day. Two of them also contain 'ad_group_name'.

The query is functioning and returning all the right values for data coming from keyword and campaign, but the values I need from ad level (conversion_name and it's values) are not. But the confusing part for me is that when I use the 'WHERE' clause and select only one row, the values are correct and match up to the source tables. Additionally, the values of a.conversion_name add up to 'conversion' total (+/- 1/2).

[Results from single row (WHERE clause)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/un9VC.png)

When I remove the WHERE clause and select the entire table, my numbers are significantly larger than they should be. The a.conversion_name values no longer add up to the 'conversion' total - in fact sometimes conversions = 0, and the a.conversion_name values return values.

[Results when selecting entire table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kU2tG.png)

[Results when selecting entire table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdNxe.png)

I think I understand why this is happening, it's a grouping issue (?), and I have searched through lots of the existing threads, tried out sub queries and DISTINCTS, but my skill level at the moment means I am really struggling to figure this out.

Should I change how things are grouped? I have also tried adding the a.conversion_name as a dimension and then selecting it, but this doesn't help either.

```
WITH raw AS (SELECT 
k.day, 
k.campaign_name,
k.ad_group_name,
k.ad_group_type, 
k.ad_group_id, 
k.campaign_id, 
k.keyword, 
k.keyword_match_type,
AVG(CASE WHEN a.conversion_name = 'Verification Submitted' THEN a.conversions END) AS conv_verification_submitted,
AVG(CASE WHEN a.conversion_name = 'Email Confirmed' THEN a.conversions END) AS conv_email_confirmed,
AVG(CASE WHEN a.conversion_name = 'Account created' THEN a.conversions END) AS conv_account_created,
AVG(CASE WHEN a.conversion_name = 'Verification Started' THEN a.conversions END) AS conv_verification_started,
AVG(CASE WHEN a.conversion_name = 'Deposit Succeeded' THEN a.conversions END) AS conv_deposit_succeeded,
AVG(CASE WHEN a.conversion_name = 'Trade Completed' THEN a.conversions END) AS conv_trade_completed,
AVG(K.clicks) as clicks, 
AVG(K.conversions) as conversions, 
AVG(K.costs) as spend, 
AVG(K.impressions) as impressions, 
AVG(k.quality_score) as quality_score, 
AVG(c.search_impression_share) as search_impression_share, 
AVG(k.search_exact_match_impression_share) as search_exact_match_impression_share, 
AVG(c.search_lost_impression_share_rank) as search_lost_impression_share_rank, 
AVG(c.search_top_impression_share) as search_top_impression_share, 
AVG(c.search_lost_impression_share_budget) as search_lost_impression_share_budget, 
FROM `bigqpr.keyword-level-data` as k
LEFT JOIN `bigqpr.campaign-level-data` as c
ON c.campaign_name = k.campaign_name and c.day = k.day
LEFT JOIN `bigqpr.ad-level-data` as a
ON a.campaign_name = k.campaign_name and a.day = k.day and a.ad_group_name = k.ad_group_name
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,a.conversion_name)
SELECT
day, 
campaign_name,
ad_group_name,
ad_group_type, 
ad_group_id, 
campaign_id, 
keyword, 
keyword_match_type,
AVG(conv_verification_submitted) as conv_verification_submitted,
AVG(conv_email_confirmed) as conv_email_confirmed,
AVG(conv_account_created) as conv_account_created,
AVG(conv_verification_started) as conv_verification_started,
AVG(conv_deposit_succeeded) as conv_deposit_succeeded,
AVG(conv_trade_completed) as conv_trade_completed,
AVG(clicks) as clicks, 
AVG(conversions) as conversions, 
AVG(spend) as spend, 
AVG(impressions) as impressions, 
AVG(quality_score) as quality_score, 
AVG(search_impression_share) as search_impression_share, 
AVG(search_exact_match_impression_share) as search_exact_match_impression_share, 
AVG(search_lost_impression_share_rank) as search_lost_impression_share_rank, 
AVG(search_top_impression_share) as search_top_impression_share, 
AVG(search_lost_impression_share_budget) as search_lost_impression_share_budget, 
FROM raw
WHERE keyword = "specifickeyword" and day = "2022-05-22" and ad_group_name = "specificadgroup"
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)
 [mre]

Comment: This seems likely to be a common error where people want some joins, each possibly involving a different key, of some subqueries, each possibly involving join and/or aggregation, but they erroneously try to do all the joining then all the aggregating or to aggregate over previous aggregations. Write separate aggregate subqueries over appropriate rows and/or aggregate (maybe distinct) case statements picking rows of (possibly join result) tables; then join the subqueries together. [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12464037/3404097)

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code & example input; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0):

I am also a beginner, but my first thought is to try an `Inner Join` instead of a `Left Join`. Sometimes this helps my result sets fit the number I'm looking for instead of being so large.